# Lazy load class in PHP

Tags: php

I want to lazy load class but with no success

```
<?php

class Employee{

    function __autoload($class){

        require_once($class);
    }


    function display(){

        $obj = new employeeModel();
        $obj->printSomthing();
    }
}
```

Now when I make this

```
function display(){
            require_once('emplpyeeModel.php');
            $obj = new employeeModel();
            $obj->printSomthing();
        }
```

It works but I want to lazy load the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `Employee` a bit:

```
class Employee {

   public static function __autoload($class) {
      //_once is not needed because this is only called once per class anyway,
      //unless it fails.
      require $class;
   }

   /* Other methods Omitted */
}
spl_autoload_register('Employee::__autoload');
```

Answer (score 6):

**__autoload** is a standalone function not a method of a class. Your code should look like this:

```
<?php

class Employee{

    function display(){

        $obj = new employeeModel();
        $obj->printSomthing();
    }
}

function __autoload($class) {
    require_once($class.'.php');
}

function display(){
    $obj = new Employee();
    $obj->printSomthing();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Example taken from the php manual:

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2(); 
?>
```

Comment: He shouldn't use `__autoload` at all

Comment: @ExplosionPills Could you explain why you say so? I am curious myself.

Comment: @sprain He should write an autoload function called something else, perhaps as part of a class as he has done, and then call `spl_autoload_register`.  Imagine this code is on a huge website with many criss-crossing dependencies on pages.  What if someone has already used `__autoload` on an app that goes untested that happens to include the file where he is defining the other `__autoload`.

Comment: can you please clarify by a sample code i am curious about you solution

Comment: @ExplosionPills that's true. but for a beginner trying to understand how all this works __autoload is the most simple method to get him going. IMHO

Comment: @user4o01 I have included it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First if all it's better to use [spl_autoload_register()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) (check the note in php's manual for autoloading).

Then back to your problem; only if the display() function is in the same directory as the employeeModel this will work. Otherwise, use absolute paths (see also [include()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [include_path setting](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)